# ComboBox not listening to events

Tags: java, swing, oop, jcombobox, eventhandler

This application shows a frame that contains different JComboBoxes and a JLabel.
An event should be generated when the user clicks the last one(style combobox) and the text in the JLabel should be formatted according to the selected choices in each combobox.

When I click on the Style combobox nothing happens.
There's also another error that I couldn't figure out:(

**OUTPUT**

[image]

```
package labtasksix;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    String NameO []= {"Select name:","TimesRoman","Serif","SansSerif","Monospaced"};
    String ColorO[]={"Select color:","RED","BLUE","GREEN"};
    String SizeO []={"Select size:","8","12","16","20"};
    String StyleO[]={"Select style:","BOLD","ITALIC","PLAIN"};

   JLabel lbl= new JLabel("Text Formatted");
   JComboBox Name= new JComboBox(NameO);
   JComboBox Colour= new JComboBox(ColorO);
   JComboBox Size= new JComboBox(SizeO);
   JComboBox Style= new JComboBox(StyleO);

    public MyFrame() {
        super("Format Frame");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(Name);
        add(Size);
        add(Style);
        add(Colour);
        add(lbl);
        Name.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        Size.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        Style.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        Colour.setMaximumRowCount(3);
    EventHandler handler= new EventHandler();
    Style.addItemListener(handler);
    }

    class EventHandler implements ItemListener{

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

        //When user chooses from the last combobox (style)
        if(e.getSource()==Style)
        {
        if(Name.getSelectedItem().equals("BOLD"))
              {
             lbl.setFont(new Font((String)Name.getSelectedItem(),Font.BOLD, (int) Size.getSelectedItem()));
              }

        if(Name.getSelectedItem().equals("ITALIC"))
              {
              lbl.setFont(new Font((String)Name.getSelectedItem(),Font.ITALIC, (int) Size.getSelectedItem()));

              }
        if(Name.getSelectedItem().equals("PLAIN"))
        {
             lbl.setFont(new Font((String)Name.getSelectedItem(),Font.PLAIN, (int) Size.getSelectedItem()));

        }
        if(Colour.getSelectedItem().equals("RED"))
              {

               lbl.setForeground(Color.red);
              }
         if(Colour.getSelectedItem().equals("BLUE"))
              {

               lbl.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
              }
          if(Colour.getSelectedItem().equals("GREEN"))
              {

               lbl.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
              }

        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Based on your code and my running of it, `Style` is not the last combobox, it's the second last one and it seems to work fine

Answer (score 1):

It is listening, but you're checking the `ComboBox.getSelectedItem()`, which hasn't been updated at the time the event is fired. The item the event relates to is referenced in the event itself; call `e.getItem()` to retrieve it:

```
Object item = e.getItem();
if (item.equals("BOLD")) {
    lbl.setFont(new Font((String) item, Font.BOLD, /* wrong: (int) Size.getSelectedItem() */ 8));
}
```

Your size calculation (commented above) is wrong too. Your size selection box holds `Strings`, so you'll have to parse them (or change the model to ints).

Also... you'll get two events for each change, `ItemEvent.DESELECTED` first (for the old item), then `ItemEvent.SELECTED`. You should check for the event you're interested in:

```
if (e.getSource() == Style && e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? I tried applying the changes you mentioned but still doesn't work.  I might have misunderstood.                                                                                                          Object item = e.getItem();
        if(e.getSource()==Style&& e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
        if(item.equals("BOLD"))
              {
             lbl.setFont(new Font((String)Name.getSelectedItem(),Font.BOLD, Integer.parseInt(Size.getSelectedItem()));// I parsed it but still get error
              }